# Numpy Broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, broadcasting, array-broadcasting

What happens when i make this operation in Numpy?

```
a = np.ones([500,1])
b = np.ones([5000,])/2
c = a + b 

# a.shape (500,1)
# b.shape (5000, )
# c.shape (500, 5000)
```

I'm having a hard time to figure out what is actually happening in this broadcast.

Comment: Did you go through the docs on broadcasting?

Comment: The one slightly tricky bit here is that by convention, if there are missing axes as in the case of your `b` they are added as ones to the _left_. I don't know whether that has any deeper reasons, it does preserve C-contiguousness, though.

Answer (score 1):

Numpy assumes for 1 dimensional arrays row vectors, so your summation is indeed between shapes (500, 1) and (1, 5000), which leads to matrix summation.

Since this is not very clear, you should extend your dimensions explicitly:

```
>>> np.arange(5)[:, None] + np.arange(8)[None, :]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Comment: "Numpy assumes for 1 dimensional arrays row vectors" - no it doesn't, or things like `(2, 2)` shape array dot `(2,)` shape array wouldn't work. 1D arrays are 1D arrays. Different operations might treat them similarly to rows or columns depending on the context.

Comment: It's more exact to say that a `(n,)` broađcasts to `(1,n)` if needed.  To avoid ambiguity expanding to  (n,1) has to be explicit.

Comment: If you really want to be explicit, use `np.newaxis` instead of `None`.